# Child not showing up in KendoTreeView Web

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

```
//treeview source
function populateTreeView(search) {
    debugger;

    var tree = $("#tvwResults").kendoTreeView({
        dataTextField: [{
            text: search.columnName,
            items: [{
                text: "activemeters"
            }]
        }],
        select: function (e) {
            console.log("Selecting ", e.node)
        },
        animation: {
            expand: {
                effects: "fadeIn expandVertical",
                duration: 600
            }
        }

    }).data("kendoTreeView");
    $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.2:6080/arcgis/rest/services/WW/WW2/MapServer/exts/RestSOE/Search%20Query?columnName=" + search.columnName + "&operand=" + search.operand + "&searchVal=" + search.searchVal + "&f=", function (data) {
        tree.dataSource.data(data);
    });
};
```

I'm really missing something here. I can see the results in the root node, showing two records, however, the "activemeters" child node isn't showing up. I'm stumbling and thankful for help. Quite a setback hoping to push these results into a pivot grid using KendoUI but the control is non-existent. I just need two columns, first listing the table column names and the second showing the details. SO grateful for your help, learning alot here.

Comment: I tried adding this: tree.append({ text: data.activemeters}), $("#tree .k-item:first"); after the tree.dataSource.data(data); no luck.

Comment: Could you share a little bit of the data you are setting on the treeview? Or, recreate the issue in a jsFiddle or jsBin? I think you have `dataTextField` set incorrectly.

Comment: Sure. This is my existing data, cut down for space sake: [
 {
  "Account Num": "210663845",
  "Address": "9 COUNTRY RD",
  "City": "HAMDENEE",  
  "Name_1": "ANDREW SMITH",
  "Name_2": "",
  "Street": "GREEN ST",
  "Street Num": "25",
  "activemeters": "T30619-00T|30078309"
 },...

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you showed isn't quite enough to tell how your hierarchy works, since that is just 1 node at 1 level, but the `dataTextField` that you have defined is incorrect. When it is specified as an array, it is supposed to be an array of strings that tells the treeview what field to use at each level of depth as the display name for the node.

I think you want something like this:

```
var tree = $("#tvwResults").kendoTreeView({
    dataTextField: ["Account Num", "activemeters"],
    select: function (e) {
        console.log("Selecting ", e.node)
    },
    animation: {
        expand: {
            effects: "fadeIn expandVertical",
            duration: 600
        }
    }
}).data("kendoTreeView");                                        

tree.dataSource.data([
    {
        "Account Num": "210663845",
        "Address": "9 COUNTRY RD",
        "City": "HAMDENEE",
        "Name_1": "ANDREW SMITH",
        "Name_2": "",
        "Street": "GREEN ST",
        "Street Num": "25",
        "items": [
            {"activemeters": "T30619-00T|30078309"}
        ]
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the 'array' does not have any depth by default. Am I confusing this with a JSON object? The ... in my data example means it repeats on this same level. Not sure how I 'get' levels in the data as it's format doesn't include it. I can add another service, which would join with the "activemeters" attribute and includes the details of the activemeters. Is this where you get the extra 'level'? Thanks, trying to grasp this.

Comment: Either the data items should contain their sub-items (as is the case in my example where I put the data into `items []`) or the treeview can made another server request to fetch the next level when the parent node is expanded. If the data from the server has the child nodes flattened into the same object, then you could use `DataSource.schema.data` http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.data to translate it on the client into a correct structure for the TreeView